# What is the default behaviour of Django Syncdb when multiple databases are defined?

Tags: python, django

I have two databases defined in my settings, one is default for postgresql and another is mysql on external system used only for read-only access.

I have separated file for models on the mysql database that is not registered in INSTALLED_APPS and when I want to access that database I use objects.using("otherdb") to get to the data...

The problem is that recently noticed strange behavior: the mysql server is now inaccessible and it crashed syncdb.

Anyway now I have this on my local settings:

```
class DumbRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, db1, db2, **hints):
        return False

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return db in ('default',)


DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['pathtomyawesomeprojectanditssettings.DumbRouter']


DATABASES = {
    "default" : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': location + 'sqlite3.db',                      
        'USER': 'django',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                     
    },

    "otherserver": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'anotherserver',  
        'USER': 'someuser',  
        'PASSWORD': 'asxasxasxasx', 
        'HOST': 'someipthatisnotup', 
        'PORT': '13306', 
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I run syncdb I get `Can't connect to MySQL server on ...`
So my question is: Why is django trying to access that server when my DumbRouter specifically says it should never use anything but default?

And more importantly how can I prevent this behavior and have a DB defined only for objects.using?

Answer (score 0):

It will use the default database.In your example your sqlite3 database will be used.To which you want to connect keep in default.
This link may helpful

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Well if it uses my default database why do I get MySQL error when I try to connect to db? it should not be even trying to connect there...

Comment: I don't know Why you used DATABASE_ROUTERS,I am not aware of database routers.I am working with django and sqlite3 as my default database.And it is working fine.